# Stale Element in for loop even though I am searching for element at the beginning of each loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a for loop to go through a table of rows and perform an action for each row, then save. After saving, the webpage is reloaded automatically. In order to avoid a stale element exception, I call on the web element at the beginning of the loop after the webpage has refreshed. It works fine for the first loop, but the second, it gives me a stale element exception. The position of the rows does not change. And the elements are clearly visible after the first loop.

I don't understand why, if i am searching for the webelement each time at the beginning of the loop rather than trying to access via a stored list or variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions for bypassing this? or if i should write my code differently?

```
 counter = 0


for i in range(5):

  time.sleep(5)

   yp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")))[counter]

  actionChains.double_click(yp).perform()
  x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")[counter].text
  new_leg_name = df.loc[df.loc[:,0] == x,1].values
  time.sleep(3)
  long_name_field = driver.find_element_by_name("id8")
  long_name_field.click()
  time.sleep(2)

  long_name_field.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
  long_name_field.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
  time.sleep(3)

  long_name_field.send_keys(new_leg_name)
  time.sleep(3)

  # add note to the bottom
  note = driver.find_element_by_name("id337")
  note.click()
  time.sleep(2)
  note.send_keys("entity name cleanup for data migration")
  time.sleep(2)


  #click on the save button
  save = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Save')]")
  save.click()
  time.sleep(6)

  counter += 1

  #click on the reload button again 

  reload =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/div/a[5]/span/span/span[1]")
  reload.click()
  time.sleep(5)
  print(counter)
```

Stale Element Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-52f0e8daec6f> in <module>
     17     EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")))[counter]
     18 
---> 19     actionChains.double_click(yp).perform()
     20     x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")[counter].text
     21     new_leg_name = df.loc[df.loc[:,0] == x,1].values

c:\users\o34639\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py in perform(self)
     78         """
     79         if self._driver.w3c:
---> 80             self.w3c_actions.perform()
     81         else:
     82             for action in self._actions:

c:\users\o34639\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py in perform(self)
     74             if encoded['actions']:
     75                 enc["actions"].append(encoded)
---> 76         self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
     77 
     78     def clear_actions(self):

c:\users\o34639\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\o34639\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
```

I've also tried using the following but still receive a stale element exception.

```
actionChains.double_click(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")[counter].perform()
```

html code below - all of the rows are represented by a table tag

```
<div class="x-grid-item-container" role="presentation" style="width: 4673px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <table id="revalgridview-3995-record-2238" role="presentation" data-boundview="revalgridview-3995" data-recordid="2238" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="  x-grid-row" role="row" aria-selected="true">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3996 x-grid-cell-first" role="gridcell" style="width:71px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-3996">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">Yes</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3997" role="gridcell" style="width:92px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-3997">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">0101</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3998" role="gridcell" style="width:85px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-3998">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">0101</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3999" role="gridcell" style="width:253px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-3999">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">test entity</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4000" role="gridcell" style="width:134px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4000">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">USD</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4001" role="gridcell" style="width:253px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4001">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">0101</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4002" role="gridcell" style="width:85px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4002">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">BP0101</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4003" role="gridcell" style="width:358px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4003">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">T0101</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4004" role="gridcell" style="width:197px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4004">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">test entity</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4005" role="gridcell" style="width:134px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4005">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">UNITED STATES OF AMERICA</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4006" role="gridcell" style="width:71px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4006">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">USNYC</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4007" role="gridcell" style="width:141px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4007">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4008" role="gridcell" style="width:120px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4008">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">NA</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4009" role="gridcell" style="width:85px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4009">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4010" role="gridcell" style="width:358px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4010">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4011" role="gridcell" style="width:127px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4011">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">No</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4012" role="gridcell" style="width:120px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4012">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">No</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4013" role="gridcell" style="width:134px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4013">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">December</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4014" role="gridcell" style="width:92px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4014">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">Yes</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4015" role="gridcell" style="width:57px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4015">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">No</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4016" role="gridcell" style="width:92px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4016">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;">No</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4017" role="gridcell" style="width:568px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4017">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;padding-left:0px;background-position-x:0px;;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-4018" role="gridcell" style="width:106px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-4018">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-
```

Comment: Can you include some of the HTML for the page you are trying to automate? Specifically, the HTML you are looking at when querying `(By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")))[counter]`. I think the `[counter]` index might be throwing this off -- you might need to re-write your XPath to pull the element directly based on counter, rather than grabbing a list of elements and picking one through `[counter]`.

Comment: Hi Christine, I have added the html to my original post. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: From your HTML sample, `//table/tbody/tr/td[6]` only returns one element. Based on the way you are using the result of `//table/tbody/tr/td[6]` as a list, I am assuming multiple elements are getting returned? The snapshot only includes one `tr` element, can you verify whether or not there are multiple `tr` elements?

Comment: there is only 1 tr element per table tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would try refactoring the following lines:

```
yp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr/td[6]")))[counter]

actionChains.double_click(yp).perform()
```

into something a little different:

```
yp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[" + (counter+1) + "]/td[6]")))

actionChains.double_click(yp).perform()
```

This code uses an XPath that takes `counter` as a row index, and waits on the **specific row** you are trying to perform the action on -- this is instead of waiting on **all** rows, and picking the row from the list which gets returned.

This is just a little more specific than what your previous code was doing. We use `counter + 1` because `WebElement` lists in XPath query are 1-based, not 0-based like Python lists.

Comment: so using your code, I still receive the the same error. however, when I instead use the click function instead of the double click, it loops row by row clicking each cell. So, the reason for the double click was to open the row and perform an action, but there is an edit button in the main menu which would open the row after clicking once. It's interesting that the double click throws a stale error but the regular click does not.

Comment: `for i in range(5):
    yp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table["+str(counter)+"]/tbody/tr/td[6]")))

    yp.click()`

Comment: Oh that is quite interesting. It seems like clicking the row the first time is changing the HTML, so the 2nd click of the double click is actually throwing the error. You might have to workaround and not use double click at all.

Comment: yes luckily there is an edit button I can use to open the rows w/o double clicking. Many thanks for your help with this. I greatly appreciate. This is going to save me hours of manual entries!! :)